# How to redirect a save button on an add list item to a "Thanks for your submission" type page?

Tags: list, redirect

I am want to create an online application using SharePoint 2013.  This is for the new hire applicants to use.  We have made the page accessible from the extranet.

The user can fill out the form, but when the save button is clicked, they are redirected to the list.  We need this save button to redirect to a "**thanks for your submission**" page.

What is the solution?  Any help is greatly appreciated.  I'm fairly new at this so any details will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript:

You can use `PreSaveAction()` function to write your custom code before submitting the form.

Just do a javascript redirect like

```
function PreSaveAction(){
     window.location.replace("thanks for your submission page url");
}
```

Comment: To add clarification - this function is already called by the Save button, injecting this code into your page should over ride the existing function and allow you to call your own code with out modifying the existing button.

Answer (score 0):

an easier way to achieve this than JS is that, you configure the SharePoint list in infopath, and then create a "thank you for submission" view in infopath, and add a "switch view" rule to the "submit" button, so that, when the "submit" button is clicked, the users will auto be redirected to the "thank you" page. this is a no code solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the SharePoint:SaveButton with the code below:

```
<input type="button" class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" value="Save" name="btnSave" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={http://thankyoupage}')}" />
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Just replace the redirect url with the url for your Thankyou page.